# Yii2: How to detect if data comes from keyboard or barcode scanner

Tags: yii2, keyboard, barcode-scanner

I have a very simple **Yii2 input field** where I will enter data from a **keyboard** or from a **barcode scanner**.

I need to know how to detect if the device used is the keyboard or the barcode scanner.

Maybe I will use a jQuery plugin that can detect it.

Comment: see here if it helps you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290898/detect-when-input-box-filled-by-keyboard-and-when-by-barcode-scanner

Answer (score 2):

with javascript, You can use a "onkeyup" event on the input box. If the event has triggered then you can consider as input from keyboard

or you can try this jQuery plugin https://plugins.jquery.com/scannerdetection/